# Javascript display clicked item from a for loop upon a click event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, wordpress, ionic-framework

Can someone please assist me here. I getting a list of POSTS from a wordpress api(get_posts). Once I get the posts, I am displaying them in a list of `<a>` tags. In every `<a>` tag there is a title and description of the post item. All of this is done dynamically in javascript within the ionic framework.

Here comes my issue. Once the list of posts are shown I need to click on a single post item from my list which then needs to show me more details (i.e. Excerpt) from it. However I am only succeeding in showing every posts details and not only the selected one. I am showing the Excerpt in a modal.

My code is below.

> **Javascript**
>   *//call JSON API upon page enter //gets list of posts and populates them in  tags // tags have have title and description added*

```
    .controller('chickenCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $window, $http, $state, $ionicModal, $ionicLoading) {

  $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(){


      $scope.result = "";
      $scope.categories = "";
      $http.get('http://dhameergovind.co.za/wp/api/get_posts/')

        .success(function(data, status, headers,config){
        var i;
        var j;
        for (i = 0; i < data.posts.length; i++) { 
            console.log(data.posts[i]);
            var image = data.posts[i].thumbnail;
            var post_id = data.posts[i].id;
            console.log(post_id);
                for (j = 0; j < data.posts[i].categories.length; j++){
                    if (data.posts[i].categories[j].title=="Chicken"){

                    var chickenTitleObj = data.posts[i].title;
                    var chickenDescObj = data.posts[i].content;
                    document.getElementById('chick').innerHTML += '<a class="item item-thumbnail-left item-block" + id='+i+'>' + '<img src ="' + image + '"/>' + '<div class="middleText">' + '<h3 class="text-wrap">' + chickenTitleObj + '</h3>' + '<p class="text-wrap">' + chickenDescObj + '</p>' + '</div>' + '</a>' + '<br/>';


                    }
                    else{
                    alert("not existing")   

                    }
            }
        }
          $scope.result = data; // for UI
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers,config){
          console.log('data error');
          $ionicLoading.hide();
        })
        .then(function(result){
          things = result.data;
          $ionicLoading.hide();
        });


  });
```

> *//once a post is clicked a modal opens to display details(Excerpt) of selected post*

```
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/recipeModal.html', { scope: $scope }).then(function(modal) { $scope.modal = modal; })


$scope.$on('modal.shown', function(e) {
      $ionicLoading.show({
        content: 'Loading',
        animation: 'ripple',
        showBackdrop: true,
        maxWidth: 200,
        showDelay: 0
      });

      $scope.result = "";
      $scope.categories = "";
      $http.get('http://dhameergovind.co.za/wp/api/get_posts/')

        .success(function(data, status, headers,config){
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < data.posts.length; i++) { 
            console.log(data.posts[i]);
            var image = data.posts[i].thumbnail;
            var post_id = data.posts[i].id;

            console.log(post_id);
            var chickenTitleObj = data.posts[i].title;
            var chickenDescExerptObj = data.posts[i].excerpt;
            document.getElementById('chickDesc').innerHTML += '<a class="item item-thumbnail-left item-block">' + '<img src ="' + image + '"/>' + '<div class="middleText">' + '<h3 class="text-wrap">' + chickenTitleObj + '</h3>' + '<p class="text-wrap">' + chickenDescExerptObj + '</p>' + '</div>' + '</a>' + '<br/>';
            $ionicLoading.hide();               

        }
          $scope.result = data; // for UI
        })

        .error(function(data, status, headers,config){
          console.log('data error');
          $ionicLoading.hide();
        })

        .then(function(result){
          things = result.data;
          $ionicLoading.hide();
        });

});

})
```

> **//HTML**

```
<ion-view view-title="Chicken Recipes">
  <ion-content>
    <div class="list">

        <div id="chick" class="input-box" ng-click="modal.show()">

        </div>

    </div>

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

> **//Modal HTML**

```
      <ion-modal-view view-title="Chicken Recipes">
        <ion-content class="padding">
          <div class="list">
            <div id="chickDesc" class="item-block input-box">

            </div>

          </div>
          <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="modal.hide()">Close</button>
        </ion-content>

      </ion-modal-view>
```

Comment: Woudn't it be better if you used ng-repeat to render the post-details ?

Comment: I unfortunately am still learning angular so am sticking to JS while I learn angular. But I will consider it to make thing a bit easier

Answer (score 0):

Your `ng-click` is on the entire list of results, so you have no way of knowing what was clicked. You need it to be on one of the repeated elements, and you need some way to know which one was clicked, like this:

```
document.getElementById('chickDesc').innerHTML += '<a ng-click="item_clicked(' + i.toString() + ');" class= ...
```

Define `item_clicked` in your controller like this:

```
$scope.item_clicked = function(index) {
    $scope.clicked_index = index;
    $scope.modal.show();
};
```

Now in your on-modal-shown, remove the for loop and just leave its body, substituting `$scope.clicked_index` instead of each use of `i`.

Also, you shouldn't call `$http.get('http://dhameergovind.co.za/wp/api/get_posts/')` again. It's inefficient, and might also cause you to see the wrong data, in case new posts have been added and the indexes don't match up. Instead, save the data the first time you get it in your success function in on-enter. Something like this:

```
$scope.posts = data
```

Optionally, and a bit more advanced, you could make an endpoint like `http://dhameergovind.co.za/wp/api/get_posts/{post_id}` to get just one post. That would make sure you have the latest data on the post you selected.

As the comment above said, you really aren't using the maximum power of Angular. With Angular, you shouldn't need to use Javascript to build the structure of your page. Writing HTML strings in your Javascript code is a sign that you're doing it wrong. Even manipulating the DOM is probably not the best way. With Angular, your Javascript code should just retrieve, send, and manipulate data, and your template should describe how that's mapped to document structure.

But my answer is the smallest change you can do to your code to make it do what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much. This will definitely set me on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you looping to display details in your modal? Also you don't need to call your URL again to get data every time you need to show modal window. Just keep the loaded data in a variable and use it for all subsequent clicks.

I assume you are opening the modal window based on user clicking the link. You already defined an id (if you think it is not unique then make it unique) for these links. That id is nothing but index for your array element which needs to be shown on modal window. Just get the array element and set the details to your `chickDesc`.